# Run grunt plugin outside of initConfig

Tags: gruntjs

Does anyone know what is the minimal pattern that I need to use a value that was set as variable with `grunt.config.set` from result of a plugin ran in `grunt.initConfig`?

Being new to both grunt and javascript, I am unclear as to how I can use this value to run another plugin, 
for example, I can run a plugin within `grunt.initConfig` to get the value I want to set but how can I now run another set of plugin?

Here's an example of what I want to run:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-template');

  grunt.initConfig({
    shell: {
      pwd: {
        command: 'pwd'
      }
    }

  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', 'shell', function() {
    grunt.config.set('pwd');

    'template': {
      'test': {
        'options': {
          'data': {
            "name": "data",
              "description": "",
              "environment": <%=pwd%>
          }
        },
        'files': {
          'project.json': ['test.tpl']
        }
      }
    }

  });

};
```

But it doesn't work as I cannot simply run the plugin template in registerTask section like I do in initConfig.

Comment: Hope you find out what's going wrong with it. Will look into it